# Openshift: How to Delete or Manage Specific Pod

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I spun up an Openshift 4.6 cluster on AWS, 3 masters, 2 Workers for learning/play. Since it was just for learning, I shut down all nodes at once using the AWS Web Console. When I brought them back up a few days later, the console will not spin up.

So I  followed this doc on [restarting the cluster](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.5/backup_and_restore/graceful-cluster-restart.html#graceful-restart-cluster). Didn't work, so I started looking at how the pods were doing for the console itself. I ran `oc get pods -n openshift-console -o wide -w` and got:

```
NAME                       READY   STATUS                     RESTARTS   AGE    IP            NODE                                         NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
console-59f557f67d-ks5kq   0/1     Pending                    0          13m    <none>        <none>                                       <none>           <none>
console-59f557f67d-q6zrc   0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          4d6h   <none>        ip-10-0-139-41.us-west-2.compute.internal    <none>           <none>
console-59f557f67d-w4q7l   0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          56m    <none>        ip-10-0-131-234.us-west-2.compute.internal   <none>           <none>
console-59f557f67d-zvxzn   0/1     UnexpectedAdmissionError   0          59m    <none>        ip-10-0-131-234.us-west-2.compute.internal   <none>           <none>
downloads-55f4ff79-lqdj7   1/1     Running                    0          59m    10.131.0.4    ip-10-0-208-19.us-west-2.compute.internal    <none>           <none>
downloads-55f4ff79-mrfzn   1/1     Running                    0          59m    10.131.0.13   ip-10-0-208-19.us-west-2.compute.internal    <none>           <none>
```

So seeing that there were a few messed up pods, I wanted to look at their logs, but I don't know how to target just a specific pod by the `NAME` column above. I tried each of these:
`oc get pods/console-59f557f67d-q6zrc`
`oc get podtemplates/console-59f557f67d-q6zrc`

I consistently get `Error from server (NotFound): pods "console-59f557f67d-q6zrc" not found`.

I then found the command `oc get pods -n openshift-console -o name` which reveals:

```
pod/console-59f557f67d-ks5kq
pod/console-59f557f67d-q6zrc
pod/console-59f557f67d-w4q7l
pod/console-59f557f67d-zvxzn
pod/downloads-55f4ff79-lqdj7
pod/downloads-55f4ff79-mrfzn
```

So I was right, it's a "pod", but then if I try to run anything like `oc logs <name>` it returns the same error that it can't be found. Is this a bug? Does Openshift think there are Pods around that no longer exist and is routing to those Pods despite not existing?

If not, what resource type is the thing under the `NAME` column? How do I target it with say an `oc logs` or `oc delete` command?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered the correct syntax in this [Redhat Bugzilla Issue](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1753040).

The correct syntax is to place the name as another argument after the namespace declaration.

Examples:

`oc describe pod -n openshift-console console-59f557f67d-zvxzn`

`oc logs pod -n openshift-console console-59f557f67d-zvxzn`

`oc delete pod -n openshift-console console-59f557f67d-zvxzn`

I'll follow up and update when I find this reference in the official docs or command line help.